# Can I combine natbib syntax and export as RTF?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, auctex

I generally use auctex to generate PDF documents. However, I now need to generate an RTF file to integrate my contribution into a collaborative Word document.

Using org-mode, I would like to use natbib citation syntax while I write. I then want to export a document as RTF with a reference list, possibly formatted as they would for a PDF file generated with auctex.

How do I use natbib-style citations and export to RTF?

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Latex2rtf](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/) on LaTeX documents generated using natbib. I don't use org-mode for this, but I imagine there is a latex file produced at some point, so I would try running latex2rtf on that.